# How can get latitude and longitude from dynamic address by php

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

how can i get lat and long from address by php .i need latitude and longitude from address .

```
$address = "Chennai, India";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address);
                  
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$responseJson = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
                  
$response = json_decode($responseJson);
                  
if ($response->status == 'OK') {
    $latitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    echo 'Latitude: ' . $latitude; 
    echo '<br />'; 
    echo 'Longitude: ' . $longitude;
} else {
    echo $response->status;
}
```

Comment: `You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs`

Comment: instead of purchasing, i suggest u to use trial version first, google give u 1 month free trial.

Comment: Can you explain your problems with the given code? Is there anything not working when you use it?

Comment: @devpro no they don't.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: can v use without API key ??

Comment: You do need a key and you must enable billing in your account. I meant they don't "give u 1 month free trial" as you mentioned. You have USD 200/month of free credit. That's a different thing. Everything is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
 <?php
    $address = "Ahmedabad, India";
    $formattedAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
            //Send request and receive json data by address
            $geocodeFromAddr = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddr.'&sensor=false&key=key');
            $output = json_decode($geocodeFromAddr);
            print_r($output);
            //Get latitude and longitute from json data
            $data['latitude']  = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
            $data['longitude'] = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
            //Return latitude and longitude of the given address
            if(!empty($data)){
                return $data;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

    ?>
```